# javascript: save characters/digits without libraries

Tags: javascript, variables, selector, document

I use a lot of the following expressions in my code:

```
document.
.getElementsBy...
.querySelector...
```

I need to save characters without using any libraries. That can be done by

```
var d = document;
```

Then, instead of `document.` I can write `d.` now. 
I am wondering if there is a simple way to do the same thing for methods
`.getElementsBy...` and `.querySelector...`.

Since these have a variable term, I cannot put the entire thing into a 
variable, like `var q = .querySelector(".class")`, because the `.class` 
changes almost every time.

Comment: you could wrap those functions on your own (with less characters).... but i dont know why you would want to ofuscate the code like that

Comment: Because I am pasting the javascript code into my search bar to execute it - and that search bar has a limited amount of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create functions to avoid adding properties to the document object as shortcut if you don't want to.

```
function gEBI(d,id)
{
   return d.getElementById(id);
}

function qS(d,s)
{
   return d.querySelector(s);
}

var d = document;
var ele1 = gEBI(d,"yourID");
var ele2 = qS(d,".class");
```

Comment: amazing, that saves me quite a lot of characters! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own shortcut functions-references manually.

```
document.gEBI = document.getElementById;
document.gEBI(id);
```

But it's not a good practice to make such shortcuts.